# Python 3: Accesing values in key in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
automobiles = {
    'germany': ['bmw', 'audi', 'mercedes benz'],
    'japan': ['honda', 'toyota', 'subaru'],
    'united states': ['ford', 'gm', 'buick'],
    'italy': ['alfa romeo', 'ferrari', 'maserati'],
    'great britain': ['jaguar', 'mini', 'aston martin'],
}
```

How can I access individual values in the different keys?  (example: Who do I access the 'audi' in the germany key or 'buick' in the united states key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a dictionary who's keys are strings and who's values are lists.

To access `'audi'` you can do this:

```
print(automobiles['germany'][1])
# which prints audi
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax: command(dict['key'][index])

In your case this would translate to:

`print(automobiles['germany'][1])`

'audi'

`print(automobiles['united states'][2])`

'buick'

The values stored in your dictionary are stored as lists. You can access elements in a list like list[n] where n is the index of the value you wish to access. Indexes start at 0 for python.